# How to Binding DataBase single column of multiple rows to textBoxes in WPF MVVM Entity FrameWork I

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF. My database has 3 columns constant:id, name and value. These 3 columns having 29 rows. My problem is 3rd column[value] 29 rows binding to 29 textboxes in xaml file like below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUjDr.png)

How to bind 29 rows to 29 textboxes. When i run the code it is display database values[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnbwZ.png)

my XAML file is

```
    <Label Name="lblCNDisplay" Content="2.  Company-Name-Display" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="94" />
    <TextBox Name="txtCNDisplay" Text="{Binding SystemConstant.Company-name-display, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="200" Width="190" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="94" TabIndex="2"   MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Name="lblAddress1" Content="3.  Address-1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="121"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtAddress1" Text="{Binding Order.Customer.AddressLine1, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="150" Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="121"  TabIndex="3"  MinHeight="15" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Name="lblAddress2" Content="4.  Address-2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="150"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtAddress2" Text="{Binding Order.Customer.AddressLine2, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="200" Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="146"  TabIndex="4" MinHeight="15" IsEnabled="False">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="lblCity" Content="5.  City" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="176"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtCity" Text="{Binding Order.Customer.City, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="100" Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="173"  TabIndex="5"   MinHeight="15" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="lblState" Content="6.  State" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="200"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtState"  Text="{Binding Order.Customer.BusinessContact, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="50" Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="200"  TabIndex="6"  MinHeight="15" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Name="lblZipCode" Content="7.  Zip-Code" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="228"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtZip" Text="{Binding Order.Customer.ContactName, Mode=TwoWay}"  MaxLength="200" Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="228"  TabIndex="7" MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
            <vmHelper:TextBoxInputMaskBehavior InputMask="99999-0000 " PromptChar="_"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="lblPhnNum" Content="8.  Phone-Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="255"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtPhnNum" Text="{Binding Order.Comments, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="170" MaxLines="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="255"  TabIndex="8" MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
            <vmHelper:TextBoxInputMaskBehavior InputMask="999/000-000 " PromptChar="_"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Name="lblFaxNum" Content="9.  Fax-Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="281"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtFaxNum" Text="{Binding Order.RouteCode, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="281"  TabIndex="9" MinHeight="15" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
            <vmHelper:TextBoxInputMaskBehavior InputMask="999/000-000 " PromptChar="_"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="lblNextRepNum" Content="10.  Next-Report-Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="307"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtNextRepNum" Text="{Binding Order.Terms_Description, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="15" Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="307"  TabIndex="10"  MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
            <vmHelper:TextBoxInputRegExBehaviour RegularExpression="^(\d*)\.{0,1}(\d*)$" MaxLength="15" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="lblCompany2" Content="11.  Company-2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="334"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtCompany2" Width="190"  MaxLength="200" MinHeight="15" Text="{Binding Order.Invoice_Date, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="334" TabIndex="11" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="lblCompany3" Content="12.  Company-3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="360"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtCompany3" Width="190" MaxLength="200" Text="{Binding SalesRepName, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="360"  TabIndex="12"    MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    </TextBox>

    <Label Name="lblCompany4" Content="13.  Company-4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="387"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtCompany4" Text="{Binding Order.Print_Order_Labels, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="200" Width="190" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="387"  TabIndex="13" MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="lblCompany5" Content="14.  Company-5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="414"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtCompany5" Text="{Binding Order.Order_TakenBy, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="200" Width="190" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="414"  TabIndex="14" MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <Label Name="lblCompany6" Content="15.  Company-6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="444"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtCompany6" Text="{Binding Order.Tax_Code, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="200" Width="190" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="442"  TabIndex="15" MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Name="lblCompany7" Content="16.  Company-7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="469"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtCompany7" Text="{Binding Order.PO_Number, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="200" Width="190" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="469"  TabIndex="16"  MinHeight="15">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Name="lblCompany8" Content="17.  Company-8 " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="496"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtCompany8" Width="190" MaxLength="200" MinHeight="15" Text="{Binding Order.Ship_Date, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="496" TabIndex="17" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior KeyUpCommand="{Binding KeyUPCommand}" ></vmHelper:KeyUpWithArgsBehavior>

        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Items Control.

Do you want to show the data in text box then use below code in your xaml otherwise use the DataGrid for table format like your image.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConstantValueList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConstantName}" Margin="2,5,5,1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: thank u so much.but  my table column have 10 rows i want to bind 10 rows into 10 textboxes

Comment: <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConstantValueList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConstantName}" Margin="2,5,5,1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl> How to assign all textboxes